# Composite Keys and Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a new project and ran into an issue with EF Core 7

It's a fairly simple situation so there must be an easy solution but I'm just stuck. Here's the situation.

A Customer has many addresses. So far so easy - just add an CustomerID column to Address and EF does it's magic and sets up the foreign key.

..but then a customer might want to save the default address among their many addresses. This is also easy at first. A DefaultAddressID? nullable Property in Customer links to an address record. The potential problem here is that the database is not guaranteeing that the  Address referenced by the DefaultAddressID? property also has a CustomerID that references back to the customer. In theory a customer could be set up so that somebody else's address is their default address. That's where I'm stuck.

I need a composite foreign key so that a customer can only have one of their own addresses as a default address.

In raw SQL this is pretty easy:

```
alter table Customers
Add constraint FK_Customer_DefaultBilltoAddress
foreign Key(DefaultBilltoAddressID,ID)
references Addresses(ID,CustomerID)
```

I've tried to replicate this in EF any number of ways but I haven't had any luck.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        .HasOne(c => c.DefaultBillToAddress)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(nameof(Address),new string[] {nameof(Customer.ID),nameof(Customer.DefaultBillToAddressID)})
        .HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Customer),new string[] {nameof(Address.CustomerID),nameof(Address.ID) })
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

I tried all kinds of options and nothing seems to make EF happy.

Comment: I do not recommend adding these checks at data level. You should have a service layer/ Business rules layer to handle them when adding/modifying objects. Also consider that adding these kind of data constraints that could possibly be checked at upper layers might decrease the insert performance of the table.

Comment: Maybe instead of adding an extra reference and field on `Customers`, just add a boolean/byte field `IsDefault` on `Addresses`? This would make queries a tad more complex, but might save you some headaches like the one you're facing.

Comment: Do you get an error? How do you know you 'haven't had any luck'?The principal entity's key in the relationship must be specified as an alternate key for the principal entity.